# How to convert a string with escaped characters into a "normal" string

Tags: javascript, parsing

Let's say that I have like this: `"\\n"`, I need to convert it to a string like if the interpreter would do it: `\n`.

A simple replace like this wouldn't work:

```
function aaa(s){
    return s.replace(/\\n/gm,'\n').replace(/\\\\/gm,'\\');
}
```

---

I need this behaviour:

- `"Line 1\nLine 2"` => `Line 1<Line break>Line 2`
- `"Line 1\\nLine 1"` => `Line 1\nLine1`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't include it in the example. I'll modify the accepted answer to translate `\r` and some others special characters too.

Comment: Do you want to normalize all newlines?  (In other words, do you want to convert `\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n` to a single representation?)

Comment: No, I want to convert just as javascript does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, and most evil, solution, is to write `return eval(s)`.
*Do not do that.*

Instead, you need to make a single `replace` call with a match evaluator, like this:

```
var escapeCodes = { 
    '\\': '\\',
    'r':  '\r',
    'n':  '\n',
    't':  '\t'
};

return s.replace(/\\(.)/g, function(str, char) {
    return escapeCodes[char];
});
```

(Tested)

Comment: It works! I will wait 2 hours until I accept the answer to make sure I get a very optimized solution.

Comment: Note that you might want to add more escape codes.  Also, this will _completely_ fail to handle `\x64`.  If you want to, I'll modify it to handle those.

Comment: Hint: `/\\\(['"\\bfnrt]|x\d{2}|\d{3}|u\d{4})/g`, then check the first char and react accordingly, calling `parseInt(substr, 8 or 16)`

Comment: I already finished it :p, I'll accept your answer and post my code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to SLaks for the answer.

Here is the final code:

```
(function(self,undefined){
    var charMappings = { 
        '\\':   '\\',
        'r':    '\r',
        'n':    '\n',
        't':    '\t',
        'b':    '\b',
        '&':    '\&'
    };
    var rg=(/\\(.|(?:[0-7]{3})|(?:x[0-9a-fA-F]{2})|(?:u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}))/gm);
    self.mapString=function(s){
        return s.replace(rg, function(str, ch) {
            switch(ch.length){
                case 1:
                    return charMappings.hasOwnProperty(ch)?charMappings[ch]:ch;
                case 2:
                case 4:
                    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(ch,16));
                case 3:
                    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(ch,8));
            }
        });
    }
})(window);
```

Comment: You can simply write `return charMappings[ch] || ch;`  Also, what's `\&`?

Comment: It's &, I don't know, but I found it in the table I was looking at .__.